# Использование Caldroid для своего приложения

Tags: java, android

Кто использовал Caldroid в своих приложениях, подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно вызвать/встроить его в код?
Как бы вот:

```
CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
t.commit();
```

но, откуда взять разметку для

```
calendar1
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.calendar1` это просто контенер `LinearLayout`, в котором будет содержаться ваш календарь.

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/calendar1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
```

Для [примера](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/blob/master/caldroidSampleActivity/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) смотрите сэмпл автора библиотеки.